# How can I source an NHibernate composite key's values from an Oracle sequence using Mapping.ByCode?

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Using NHibernate's `Mapping.ByCode`, how can I source the initial values of a composite key from Oracle sequences?

```
ComposedId(map =>
{
    map.Property(x => x.Column1);
    map.Property(x => x.Column2);
});
```

The below works for a single key, but `ComposedId` uses `IComposedIdMapper`, which doesn't seem to have an equivalent to `IIdMapper`'s `Generator`:

```
Id<decimal>(x => x.Id, o =>
{
    o.Column("ID");
    o.Generator(Generators.Native, genMapping => genMapping.Params(new { sequence = "MY_SCHEMA.MY_ID_SEQ" }));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one column is generated from a sequence incremented at each insert, it ought to be unique alone. So it could be mapped as a single column id.

Composite id does not allow for generators because they are by essence assigned, by example to some primary keys of other tables, or to some enumerated value like a "type of the entity" combined a key of wome owner, a rank, whatever.

You may still use a sequence for assigning one part of the composite id if you really have to, but you will have to call by yourself the sequence for getting its value and assigning it to your composite id. Use `ISession.CreateSQLQuery("adequate sql for your db")` for doing this. You may build your sql with the help of the dialect object, exposed by your session factory. (Call `ISession.GetSessionImplementation().Factory.Dialect.GetSequenceNextValString("sequenceName")`.)

But normally, if you want to use a sequence for an id, use a single column id, not a composite one.

It looks to me quite wrong to use a composite-id with one column generated with a unique value: better avoid composite id whenever possible. If the value is unique, it does not need any additional column for being a primary key.

By the way, in most cases, NHibernate will not care whether the mapped id is actually declared as a primary in the database or not, whether an association key is declared as a foreign key or not, ... It matters only if you use NHibernate for schema generation. So better map them in the way that makes more sense, unless you have some weird things preventing you to simplify them in the NHibernate mapping.

Comment: I agree the design is a bit odd. This is an existing repo where this particular entity hasn't been used before and I'm getting it up and running. It looks like there are some situations where the keys are set manually and some where they need to be auto-generated, so I think your `CreateSQLQuery` with manual assignment will work. Thanks!

Comment: @EricEskildsen, I have readjusted it the code using the Dialect. I had forgotten this property was available only from the implementation interface. In the answer I provide a "no cast" solution. From a `ISessionFactory`, it could be done by casting it to `ISessionFactoryImplementor` instead.